# JavaFX - How to apply different colors for words in Label

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX. I want to make the text of Label with different colors.

For Example:

Label : "sourav ganguly"

Ouput: sourav(as red color) ganguly(as blue color)

I tried but i didn't get it. Please can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could possibly use setStyle for Label and set the color you need.

```
label.setStyle("-fx-color: red");
```

[see more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor)

Comment: There is no css property like "-fx-color" in both 1.3 and 2.x JavaFX versions. Also the link you provided points to the old version of JavaFX.

Comment: Ooops))) [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/label.htm)  it could be better :)